# Is it possible in Virtualbox to allocate more hard disk space to a guest VM than a host machine has?

Tags: virtualbox

My colleague and I have laptops with 320GB HDD. We are both attempting to install Oracle E-Business Suite. My colleague is using virtualbox and demonstrated how he allocated 500GB of disk space for his guest OS. I am using Vmware but it cannot allow me to allocate more disk space to my guest OS than is actually available on my laptop which seems pretty logical. I am just wondering how that works.

Answer (score 6):

When you create a VM in Virtualbox (or most other VM environments) and assign it a HDD allocation type you are setting the maximum amount of space available to the guest OS. This will be created in the form of a virtual disk which is visible to the guest and assigned against the host physical disk. These disks come in two forms:

**Fixed**

The space you allocate to the guest machine is written to the physical disk which allocated the total amount set against the host disk. So if you provide a fixed 100GB against the guest this amount will be written and allocated on the physical disk.

**Dynamic**

Again you allocated a maximum amount of space against the host physical disk which is provided to the guest in the form of a virtual disk. In this instance the amount of initial data written is a fraction of the allocation. So, you assign 100GB dynamic disk space to the host only a couple GB might be written to the disk with the remaining space being allocated and written as the guest uses it.

As you can see with dynamic the space allocation for the guest isn't written to the host until it is used, so if you where to set a higher amount against the guest it doesn't mean it will be removed from host usage until it is actually used by the guest.

Source: [virtualizationadmin](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/faq/difference-fixed-dynamic-virtual-hard-disk.html)